# Подпись SOAP сообщения средствами WSE 3.0

Tags: c#, soap, wcf

Добрый день, помогите разобраться с WS-Security.
Пытаюсь подписать SOAP сообщение с использованием WSE 3.0 в VS2010

```
MessageSignature msign = new MessageSignature( new X509SecurityToken( UserCert ) );
```

где `UserSert - X509Certificate2`

Но при попытке сформировать подпись падает с ошибкой
*WSE2382: Key Type is not valid.*
Насколько я понимаю проблема кроется в настройках сертификата. Сообщение планирую передавать по открытому каналу данных.

Подскажите в чем суть данной ошибки и какие могут быть пути решения?

Answer (score 1):

Ключевая пара - пара простых чисел. С точки зрения криптографии любой ключ может использоваться для подписания.

Но с точки зрения сертификата (открытый ключ + набор  аттрибутов) можно задать аттрибуты так, что возможности использования ключевой пары будут строго специализированными.

Например, только для шифрования. Только для подписания. Все политики применения.

Предполагаю, что используемый сертификат создан не для подписания, а только для шифрования или чего-то ещё.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3280

```
  id-ce-keyUsage OBJECT IDENTIFIER ::=  { id-ce 15 }

  KeyUsage ::= BIT STRING {
       digitalSignature        (0),
       nonRepudiation          (1),
       keyEncipherment         (2),
       dataEncipherment        (3),
       keyAgreement            (4),
       keyCertSign             (5),
       cRLSign                 (6),
       encipherOnly            (7),
       decipherOnly            (8) }
```